# selenium web scraping can not save excel go next page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

try to scraping property website

https://28hse.com/en/buy

my code repeat writing the first page to excel 2 times

I guess I need the while loop the

```
page = chrome.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="block_search_results"]/div[4]/div/a[11]')     
page.click()`
```

and I cant writing the latest property but default property only

I guess I use the `response` not the `chrome`

`response = requests.get("https://www.28hse.com/buy")`

`chrome.get("https://www.28hse.com/en/buy/")`

```
import requests
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

def find_nth(haystack, needle, n):
start = haystack.find(needle)
while start \>= 0 and n \> 1:
start = haystack.find(needle, start+len(needle))
n -=1
return start

chrome = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
chrome.get("https://www.28hse.com/en/buy/")

page = chrome.find_element(By.XPATH,
'//\*\[@id="mainMenuDiv"\]/form\[2\]/div/div\[5\]/div\[2\]/div')
page.click()

time.sleep(2)
last = chrome.find_element(By.XPATH,
'//*\[@id="mainMenuDiv"\]/form\[2\]/div/div\[5\]/div\[2\]/div/div\[2\]/*\[@data-value="latest"\]')

last.click()

# time.sleep(5)

response = requests.get("https://www.28hse.com/buy")

df = pd.DataFrame (columns=\["title", "district", "url","phone","address"\])

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
results = soup.find_all(class\_="item property_item")

for page in range(1, 3):
for header in results:

        #district
        district = header.find(class_="district_area")
        d = district.select_one("a").getText()
    
        #url
        # url = header.find(class_="detail_page")
        u =  header.find("a",{"class":"detail_page"}).get("href")
    
        #phone&address
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
        chrome = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
        chrome.get(u)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(chrome.page_source, 'html.parser')
        chat = chrome.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'shortPhone')
        chat.click()
        # time.sleep(1)
        phone = soup.find(class_="fullPhone")
        ph = str(phone.get_text())
        address = soup.find(class_='table_right last')
        ad = str(address.get_text().replace("\n",""))
    
    
        s = pd.Series([t, d,u, ph, ad],index=["title", "district", "url","phone","address"])
        df = df._append(s,ignore_index=True)
        df.to_csv("28hse.csv",encoding="utf-8-sig",index=False)
        try:
            page = chrome.find_element(By.XPATH,
            '//*[@id="block_search_results"]/div[4]/div/a[11]')
            page.click()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use their Ajax URL to obtain the data for next pages, for example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = {
    "form_data": "page={page}&searchText=&myfav=&myvisited=&item_ids=&sortBy=&is_grid_mode=&search_words_thing=default&buyRent=buy&mobilePageChannel=&cat_ids=&search_words_value=&is_return_newmenu=0&plan_id=&propertyDoSearchVersion=2.0&sortBy=default&locations=&locations_by_text=0&mainType=&mainType_by_text=0&price=&price_by_text=0&areaOption=&areaOption_by_text=0&areaRange=&areaRange_by_text=0&roomRange=&roomRange_by_text=0&searchTags=&searchTags_by_text=0&others=&others_by_text=0&landlordAgency=&landlordAgency_by_text=0&yearRange=&yearRange_by_text=0&floors=&floors_by_text=0&more_options=&more_options_by_text=0"
}
api_url = 'https://www.28hse.com/property/dosearch'

payload = {}
for page in range(1, 4):   # <-- increase number of pages here
    payload['form_data'] = data['form_data'].format(page=page)
    resp = requests.post(api_url, data=payload).json()
    if resp:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(resp['data']['results']['resultContentHtml'], 'html.parser')
        # I don't understand what's written on the page, so just grab some basic info here:
        for item in soup.select('.item .header'):
            print(item.get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
最後一減，把握機會
快閃優惠，底價有驚喜
全埸至平#3房工人房 #有匙雅裝
【售】步行朗屏西鐵•市區屋苑式•2F連天台
不可代替的超級兩房則王
即走荀盤 有裝修 內園景 立即約睇還價 可試95X萬
【包借8成】獨立內廁 買一得兩層 5G智能工廈 投資之選
低水，靚景，私隱度高，戶戶海景，連車位出售
長露台，開揚山景
獨家！獨家！居屋兩房積皇，近馬鐵配套齊，絕對實盤
天盛苑ღ西鐵站旁ღ實用抵住
東南海 露台兩房 咪走寶 下間貴2百萬
560萬？？？［實盤］歡迎查詢 多一個機會
（實盤）銀行估凸價，三房套厠，高層內園，林生約睇 9623 7273
*厘印費100蚊* *厘印費100蚊*293呎*一減再減265萬
近鐵最荀入場 俾票即走
@@EKING有好盤!日看海景遠洋、夜景美不勝收！...數年雅緻裝修,即買即住！
超荀盤，急走 有意致電
「東南光猛 開揚園景 間隔四正 」Tim 68088950
【業主急售】靚裝 實盤！Ken 9803 3335
濕地公園低密度住宅，私隱度高，環境清幽，樓下有一田超市
東南方向 泳池景觀 豪華裝修 嘉湖山莊
一期三房套海景樓皇 MS SUM 64461667 市塲罕有 極少放盤
雙露台，東南向，望靚景
海堤灣㫠 3房套房加工人房 $1050 萬
利嘉閣推介✿東南3房遊艇會海景✿歡迎來電查詢
$650萬 中原主區 有匙 罕有高層 東南放盤
【即走筍盤】35年【本週精選】
長露台，有層數最平
西鐵站 巨積 真盤 隨時約睇
正南風水樓 靚裝修3房＋儲物房 約睇
高層雙露台之選，呎價超抵
罕有劈價 有電車位 無使用限制 送稅送律師費
【 真盤源。有裝低水3房套連車】急放、時尚設計！
罕有高層海景1房半單位
【包借8成】最後1間$3xx萬 買一層送你一層 高回報投資
向南樓 海景 可做925 靚裝修
UNIVERSITY HILL抽唔到?唔洗灰心 呢度幫到你
「御龍山」 高層馬場 靚河景 業主誠售 可以約睇樓
大埔 半山州 3號 獨立屋連花園地8100呎
連天台海景村屋,包車位.行10分鐘到廣福邨
前排一線無敵大海景 全屋豪華裝修
開揚山景，廳房方正
銀湖天峰2房梗廚高層內園新裝即住
絕版內廁 雙層巴士高度樓底！高智能甲廈低成本高回報
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!!! its clear and beautiful code!